# Is it okay to ask multiple questions in one thread related to the same topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on something that is rather complex to explain and has 3-4 issues that need to be solved. Should I post individual threads for each issue or can I post something general like 'I'm working on doing this, but this approach has multiple issues, do you have some suggestions in solving it?'

Comment: No, one question per question please, and be specific.